# Como selecionar apenas 1 registro por mês com SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela de vendas e gostaria de selecionar as vendas dos clientes, porém se o cliente fez mais de uma venda por mes, eu gostaria que trouxesse a mais antiga apenas, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Eu não tenho um código SQL pra fornecer por não saber por onde começar, mas tenho a tabela em questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu gostaria que fosse o retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que a linha 2 sumiu, pois o cliente "João" fez 2 compras no mes de Janeiro e trouxe apenas a compra mais antiga dele.

Estou apenas estudando, essas tabelas são apenas fictícias.

Comment: A compra mais antiga do mês de janeiro de josé não seria dia 2?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic No caso a compra do dia 02/01 é a mais recente, uma vez que está mais proxima do dia atual, logo, a do dia 01/01 é a mais antiga dele.

Comment: Entendi, fiz um exemplo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que eu entendi se quer o valor minimo da data por **mês** (que é a compra mais antiga) de um determinado **nome**, exemplo:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
    t1.nome,
    t1.data_compra, 
    t1.valor_compra 
FROM Compras t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT nome, MONTH(data_compra) as m, 
            MIN(data_compra) as c FROM Compras t2   
            GROUP BY nome, MONTH(data_compra)) AS t2 
  ON t1.nome = t2.nome AND t1.data_compra = t2.c
```

[Veja exemplo online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3e40/1)

Eu fiz baseado nas duas tabelas e com um `INNER JOIN` trouxe os valores por nome, mês e data mais recentes.

Comment: Antes da alteração p/ colocar o `INNER JOIN` já tinha resolvido meu problema, agora tenho um outro problema, não é relacionado ao tema dessa pergunta, vou tentar resolver sozinho, caso não consiga, voltarei aqui no StackOverflow. Muito obrigado pela ajuda Virgilio.